# Rox Xamarin Video 2.1.0 issue

Tags: xamarin

I'm working with Rox Xamarin Video 2.1.0. in xamarin forms
there is url [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rox.Xamarin.Video/)
I tried to make video view like sample project. but it is not woking.
sample project is working well, but my project is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide settings in info.plist.

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourDomainName.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already found the solution. It works as well.
But I faced another problem : if my internet speed is bad or does not exist the video file on server, the player displays "can't play this video".
as long as I click ok button, the message displays again in android phone.

Comment: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi
i am also facing issues in ios the vidoes are not playing above ios 10.2 version ,can u help me on these issue

Comment: did you add above setting to plist file?

Comment: yes i have added the above settings it is working upto 10.2 version after that my screen is showing white

Comment: i have posted the issue in below urls.u can check once
[See here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178613/mp4video-is-not-playing-in-xamarin-ios)
[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247253/in-xamarin-ios-videos-are-not-playing-above-ios-10-version)